# Improvement of Jensen inequality for random variables

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, convex-analysis, gaussian-integral

Jensen inequality implies that for every real random variable $X$ and every integer $n\in \mathbb N$
$$ (\mathbb E[X^2])^n \,\leq\, \mathbb E[X^{2n}]$$
by convexity of the function $x\mapsto x^n$ for $x\geq0$.

Now if we apply the previous inequality to a Gaussian random variable $X$ of mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$ we find:
$$ \sigma^{2n} \,\leq\, \sigma^{2n}\, (2n-1)!!$$
which of course is not very good for large $n$ since $(n-1)!!$ grows faster than exponential.

Is there an alternative / improvement of Jensen inequality that bounds $(\mathbb E)^n$ with a linear operator defined on a suitable space of random variables functions of $X^2$ and preserving exponential growth for large $n$?

**Edit.** I would be happy enough if I could do that for all $X$ having a strong log-concave distribution on $\mathbb R$, namely
$$\mathbb E [\varphi(X)] \,=\, \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\, \varphi(x)\,e^{-U(x)} \,dx $$
with $U''(x)\geq\lambda>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R\,$, for all $\varphi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ having polynomial growth.
Notice that the Gaussian case corresponds to $U(x)=(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2) + \frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi\sigma^2)$.

**Edit 2.** A possible modification of this question could be: for which family of random variables it holds true
$$ (\mathbb E[X^2])^n \,\leq\, \frac{c^n}{(2n-1)!!}\,\mathbb E[X^{2n}]$$
for some $c>0$ and all $n\in\mathbb N\,$?
Centred Gaussian random variables for example satisfy the inequality with $c=1$.

Comment: The question lack clarity. If you want a bound on $(\mathbb{E})^n$ which grows exponentially with $n$, then the bound $(\mathbb{E})^n\le(\mathbb{E})^n$ works. So there is no real question, unless one clarifies what kind of algebraic formulas are allowed on the right-hand side of the bound.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam I specified that the bound should be a linear operator in fact

Comment: linear operator on what space?

Comment: on a suitable space of random variables which are functions of $X$

Comment: Good, then i suggest editing your question and adding that piece of information.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam done, thank you